# encrypt kubernetes pvc storage using customer owned key

Tags: kubernetes, encryption, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I create and run own Kubernetes cluster, using compute/network of GCP (or AWS). No GKE, AKS.

I need to encrypt dynamically provisioned PV using my customer's own key.
Customer requirements means, we build our own KMS and use it for customer key. GCP (or AWS) own KMS is out of question.

How to go about this?
For example GCP -
When I use GCP's CSI driver (pd.csi.storage.gke.io), it appears to allow only GCP KMS. I need to use own.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: custcmk-gcpcsi-sc
provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  disk-encryption-kms-key: projects/key-project-id/locations/location/keyRings/key-ring/cryptoKeys/key
```

Of course, in above example, key is specified in storage class. In actual use, I have to use different customer keys per storage provision.
Is it possible to specify key in PVC instead?

Basically, our clusters are spread over cloud providers GCP, Azure, AWS.., so the maximum extent of platform specific resource we can use is compute/network.

Has anyone dealt with similar situation successfully?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to specify key in PVC instead?

Unfortunately it is not possible to do it on the [PVC level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#persistentvolumeclaim-v1-core).

As a workaround you could use [Customer-managed encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys) but you would have to use GCP KMS and not your own built ones.

Comment: yep, these are the restrictions, that I'd like to find solution for